# How to Extract Zip Files with non-Unicode non-Latin Filenames?

Tags: encoding, filenames, zip

Sometimes you come by Zip files with file or directory with some unrecognized characters in the names so you can't extract them. What tools do you use to extract them in properly converted filenames?

Comment: I didn't vote you down, but you would be better served to ask a question ("how do I extract zip files with non-unicode non-latin filenames?") and submit your solution as the answer, and then accept it. (that way you also get upvotes on your answer if it's useful). *edit* beaten to it!

Comment: +1 as it sounds useful ... but please submit it as answer ... not just question

Comment: Hmm, I thought self-answering was okay.. I saw some "questions" that were actually tutorials. Okay, I'll try that. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I searched the web but failed to find a good script. So out of necessity I wrote a Python script myself. Hope it comes handy for someone.

Any suggestions are welcome, especially if you know this will not work in some special cases. Please don't pick on the untidy coding style.

```
import os,sys,zipfile

x, fn = sys.argv
enc = 'utf-8'

zipf = zipfile.ZipFile(fn)
for x in zipf.infolist():
    fn = x.filename
    fne = fn.encode(enc)
    if os.sep in fne:
        path = fne[:fne.rindex(os.sep)]
        if not os.path.exists(path): os.makedirs(path)
    if fne.endswith(os.sep): continue
    f = open(fne,'wb')
    f.write(zipf.open(fn).read())
    f.close()
```